# Баг вьюхи при верстке

Tags: android

Кто-то может объяснить, что перекрывает кнопки и фон (те что выделены)? Слева видна иерархия вьхи, внизу - параметры 
[image: клик]

Comment: а более верхний linearlayout? может он, а внутренние просто overflow hidden получаются.

Comment: а на девайсе как отображается? может это проблема эклипса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вложеность вьюх четкая была, на девайсе также с багом было. Решилось - удалил пару глюченых леяутов и накастомил по новой, работает нормально.